# What is the difference between Fulcrum Racing 4 and racing 6 wheels?

Tags: wheels, road

I know that specialized uses a custom wheel from fulcrum racing that leaves them with a unique numbering system not found on the Fulcrum site.

Backstory is that i have 4's on one bike and 6's on another. As I plan to sell the older of the two bikes I want to keep the better of the two wheel sets.

Comment: This is a very, very specific question and I fear it really falls under the [off-topic "shopping" category](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/276/do-we-go-shopping). The real answer is "keep the wheelset you prefer", and if you can't tell the difference, sell the one that's worth the most. Or try to sell both and pull the remaining one from sale when the other sells.

Comment: You may try an email to the manufacturer (or Specialized) directly.  They may not have the information on their website for older or manufacturer specific models, but I am pretty sure a product specialist at one company (or the other) could give you a very immediate answer.

Comment: Keep the ones with the lowest mileage.  Or keep both bikes - remember everyone needs N+1.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, the smaller the number - the higher up the Fulcrum series.

Fulcrum produce OEM wheels for manufacturers and these are supplied to manufacturers with "even" numbers which do not appear on the manufacturer's site. The number falling between the official numbering series *usually* indicates the wheel being an amalgamation of wheel series. This would be something like a 3 series rim with a 5 series hub and so on. The other point with OEM products is they are often made on production lines outside of the mfrs normal line of products.